# cbind warnings : row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I have below line of code for cbind, but I am getting a warning message everytime.
Though the code still functions as it should be, is there any way to resolve the warning?

```
dateset = subset(all_data[,c("VAR1","VAR2","VAR3","VAR4","VAR5","RATE1","RATE2","RATE3")])
dateset = cbind(dateset[c(1,2,3,4,5)],stack(dateset[,-c(1,2,3,4,5)]))
```

Warnings :

```
Warning message:
   In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
        row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The code still functions as it should be"; you can use try() to supress the warning:    dateset = try(cbind(dateset[c(1,2,3,4,5)],stack(dateset[,-c(1,2,3,4,5)])), silent = TRUE)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I'm guessing your `data.frame` has `row.names`:

```
A <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                b = c(1, 2, 3), 
                c = c(4, 5, 6), 
                row.names=c("A", "B", "C"))

cbind(A[1], stack(A[-1]))
#   a values ind
# 1 A      1   b
# 2 B      2   b
# 3 C      3   b
# 4 A      4   c
# 5 B      5   c
# 6 C      6   c
# Warning message:
# In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
#   row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
```

---

What's happening here is that since you can't by default have duplicated `row.names` in a `data.frame` and since you don't tell R at any point to duplicate the `row.names` when recycling the first column to the same number of rows of the stacked column, R just discards the `row.names`.

Compare with a similar `data.frame`, but one without `row.names`:

```
B <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                b = c(1, 2, 3), 
                c = c(4, 5, 6))

cbind(B[1], stack(B[-1]))
#   a values ind
# 1 A      1   b
# 2 B      2   b
# 3 C      3   b
# 4 A      4   c
# 5 B      5   c
# 6 C      6   c
```

---

Alternatively, you can set `row.names = NULL` in your `cbind` statement:

```
cbind(A[1], stack(A[-1]), row.names = NULL)
#   a values ind
# 1 A      1   b
# 2 B      2   b
# 3 C      3   b
# 4 A      4   c
# 5 B      5   c
# 6 C      6   c
```

---

If your original `row.names` are important, you can also add them back in with:

```
cbind(rn = rownames(A), A[1], stack(A[-1]), row.names = NULL)
#   rn a values ind
# 1  A A      1   b
# 2  B B      2   b
# 3  C C      3   b
# 4  A A      4   c
# 5  B B      5   c
# 6  C C      6   c
```

Comment: Sorry, Ananda.  I wasn't trying to challenge you at all.

Comment: @RichardScriven, didn't mean for it to seem that way and have you delete your answer. As I indicated, `unlist` *should* have a performance edge (not to mention that it will work with `factor`s, which `stack` won't). In fact, I use it in my current version of my [`Stacked` function](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/blob/devel/R/Stacked.R#L76) (which was originally based on `stack`) and I thought I would comment with the observations I've found in the process.

Comment: Great. I had the same warning message with ``transform()`` and the same solution worked: ``transform(data,..., row.names = NULL)``

Comment: Same for me.  Simply `cbind(df1, df2, row.names = NULL)` did the trick.